# Pass any method of an object as a paramter in a function

Tags: c#

The title is may be not clear enough, but I'll show you a short program in order to make you understand what I want to do:

```
Class Program
{
   private static Obj A = new Obj(...);

   private static void Function(AnyMethodOfMyObject() m)
   {
      object[] result = A.m();
      ...
   }

   static void main()
   {
      double a,b,c = 0;
      string d = " ";
      Function(MethodX(a,b,c));
      Function(MethodY(d,a,b));
      ...

   }
}
```

The methods will always return the same type which is an object[], but I don't have the same number/type of argument.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do and what is expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply with a `Func<object[]>`:

```
class Program
{
   private static Obj A = new Obj(...);

   private static void Function(Func<object[]> m)
   {
      object[] result = m();
      ...
   }

   static void main()
   {
      double a,b,c = 0;
      string d = " ";
      Function(() => A.MethodX(a,b,c));
      Function(() => A.MethodY(d,a,b));
      ...

   }
}
```

`Func<object[]>` is a delegate (broadly, a reference to a method) which does not take any parameters, and which returns an array of objects. While `MethodX` takes 3 parameters (`a,b,c`), we can create a new anonymous method without doesn't take any parameters itself, and which just calls `MethodX` and passes in the values of `a`, `b` and `c` (they're captured at the point that we create this new anonymous method). This is what `() => MethodX(a, b, c)` does.

---

If you have different `Obj` instances and you want to control which one the method is called on, then use a `Func<Obj, object[]>`. This takes an `Obj` as a parameter, and returns an `object[]` as before.

```
class Program
{
   private static Obj A = new Obj(...);

   private static void Function(Func<Obj, object[]> m)
   {
      object[] result = m(A);
      ...
   }

   static void main()
   {
      double a,b,c = 0;
      string d = " ";
      Function(x => x.MethodX(a,b,c));
      Function(x => x.MethodY(d,a,b));
      ...

   }
}
```

Comment: I think they want to call the method of an instance of `Obj` so a `Func<Obj, object[]>` would be more like it so they could do `object[] result = m(A);`

Comment: Can I also implement your method if I have other arguments in my Function ?

Comment: @user676767 sure, just use a `Func<As, Many, Arg, Types, As, You, Want, object[]>`. The last item is the return type, the ones before are the types of your parameters.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, if I have my Function like :                                  private static void Function(Func<Obj, object[]> m, double b, string, c), can I still pass the other argument using the anonymous method ?

Comment: @user676767 I don't follow. You can do `Func<Obj, double, double, object[]> m, double b, double c) { object[] result = m(A, b, c); }`

Comment: In reality, I simplified the problem, in my Function I have another argument, like:   private static void Function(double a,Func<Obj, object[]> m). How can I pass the double argument named "a" in the static main ?

Comment: @user676767 By doing `Function(valueOfA, ...)`? I'm afraid I don't know what your actual code looks like: whether the method on `Obj` takes `a` as a parameter, which the value of `a` should be captured (as the code in my answer is doing), or whether it can have different values at different times...